# How to update ruby dependencies?

Tags: ruby, octopress

I want to install Octopress, that works, but I can't use java highlighting because pygments.rb 0.3.x doesn't support it. So I tried to update to a newer one:

```
$ gem install -V pygments.rb
```

which fetches 0.5.4.
Then I changed the Gemfile to

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

group :development do
  gem 'rake', '~> 10.2'
  gem 'jekyll', '~> 0.12'
  gem 'rdiscount', '~> 2.0.7'
  gem 'pygments.rb', '~> 0.5.4'
  gem 'RedCloth', '~> 4.2.9'
  gem 'haml', '~> 3.1.7'
  gem 'compass', '~> 0.12.2'
  gem 'sass', '~> 3.2'
  gem 'sass-globbing', '~> 1.0.0'
  gem 'rubypants', '~> 0.2.0'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9'
  gem 'stringex', '~> 1.4.0'
  gem 'liquid', '~> 2.3.0'
  gem 'directory_watcher', '1.4.1'
end

gem 'sinatra', '~> 1.4.2'
```

and executed

```
$ bundle update pygments.rb
```

but I get

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "pygments.rb":
  In Gemfile:
    jekyll (~> 0.12) ruby depends on
      pygments.rb (~> 0.3.2) ruby

    pygments.rb (0.5.4)
```

How can I solve this? (I'm not familiar with ruby).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've limited the maximum version of jekyll to 0.x, which limits your maximum version of pygments to 0.3.x. You can't go to pygments 0.5.x while your explicitly limited version of jekyll depends on a lower version of pygments.

You need to remove the limit on the jekyll version; replace

```
gem 'jekyll', '~> 0.12'
```

with

```
gem 'jekyll'
```

and then make sure that your program doesn't break after upgrading both jekyll and pygments.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. Unfortunately `rake generate` doesn't work anymore. It shows me the help information with a list of some possible commands, like `build`. But if I execute `rake build` I get `rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'build'` But that's another question I take care about it tomorrow.